# JavaScript current URL check

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how I would get JavaScript to check if a user is on a certain URL so i can build an if statement from the result.

My reasoning is that if a user clicks on a link in the menu and they are currently on trucks.php the javascript will redirect them to a certain page. If they are not on trucks.php they will be directed to a different page.

Cheers guys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The current location is in `location.href`.

The location object also contains some other useful fields:

- location.hash: The part after the # in the URL
- location.host: Hostname including port (if specified)
- location.hostname: Just the hostname
- location.pathname: The requested URI without protocol/host/port; starting with a /
- location.port: The port - only if one is specified in the URL
- location.protocol: Usually 'http:' or 'https:' - mind the colon at the end

In your case the most fail-safe way to check if the filename is trucks.php is this:

```
var parts = location.pathname.split('/');
if(parts[parts.length - 1] == 'trucks.php') {
    location.href = 'some-other-page';
}
```

If you want to redirect without keeping the current page in history, use the following code instead of the `location.href` assignment:

```
location.replace('some-other-page');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the update mate. It will work with out any editing when I upload to my sever.

Answer (score 4):

Use `window.location.href` to get  the current URL, or `window.location.pathname` to get just the path.  For your specific problem, just the path name is required for the solution:

```
if (window.location.pathname == "/trucks.php")
    window.location = "/somewhereelse.php";
```

Check out the [MDC documentation for *window.location*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location).

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location